# Get zero count on subset of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble figuring out what I feel like must be a pretty simple problem.  I am really annoyed I have had this much trouble figuring this out, but I am at the point I am ready to ask someone else.

I have a table that is basically a bunch of key-value pairs, where the keys and values can all be repeated.  I have another table that I can use to filter the values in the first table.

I want to take the values from the second table, and use it to filter down the key-value pairs in the first table, and get a GROUP BY count of how many keys are left in the first table.  I also want that count to return 0 when the second table resulted in all the rows for a given key to be filtered out.

I know that may be hard to visualize, so here is a SQL Fiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c186ef

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get SQL Fiddle to run the query I put in there, even though I can run it in my IDE.  But hopefully this conveys what I am trying to do.
Here are the SQL statements I have been trying against the tables in SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT mtkv2.key, COALESCE(count(mtkv2.value), 0) cnt
  FROM matt_test_key_values mtkv1
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN matt_test_key_values mtkv2 ON mtkv1.key = mtkv2.key 
 WHERE mtkv2.value in (SELECT value FROM matt_test_values)  
 GROUP BY mtkv2.key

SELECT mtkv1.key, COALESCE(count(mtkv1.key), 0) cnt
  FROM matt_test_key_values mtkv1
 WHERE mtkv1.value not in (SELECT value FROM matt_test_values)
 GROUP BY mtkv1.key

SELECT mtkv1.key, COALESCE(count(mtkv1.value), 0) cnt
  FROM matt_test_key_values mtkv1
  LEFT JOIN matt_test_key_values mtkv2 ON mtkv1.key = mtkv2.key
   AND mtkv1.value = mtkv2.value
   AND mtkv2.value IN (SELECT value FROM matt_test_values)
 GROUP BY mtkv1.key
```

I have been messing around with the different SQL there a lot, so it probably has some other errors at this point.  I am not so much asking about how to fix those as I am trying to find out how this should be done correctly in the first place

Sample data can be seen int he SQL Fiddle, but here it is just in case:

```
create table matt_test_values (value varchar2(200))
insert into matt_test_values values('1')
create table matt_test_key_values (key varchar2(200), value varchar2(200))
insert into matt_test_key_values values('1', '1')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('1', '2')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('1', '3')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('2', '1')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('2', '2')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('3', '1')
insert into matt_test_key_values values('4', '2')
```

The output I would hope to get is something like:

```
key   cnt
---   ---
1     2 //after removing the "1" value that matches, there are two rows left
2     1 //after removing the "1" value that matches, there is one row left
3     0 //after removing the "1" value that matches, there are zero rows left - this is the result I am having trouble getting
4     1 //after removing the "1" value that matches, there is one row left
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to capture the zero counts for keys where all the values are eliminated. This solution uses a sub-query to get the set of all keys; the outer join means you will get 0 when there are no matches in the set of remaining keys.

```
with cte as (
    select distinct key
    from matt_test_key_values
    )
    , mtkv as (
    select * from matt_test_key_values 
    where value not in ( select mtv.value from matt_test_values mtv)
    )
select cte.key
        , count(mtkv.value) vals
from cte
     left outer join mtkv
     on mtkv.key = cte.key
group by cte.key
order by cte.key
/
```

> " the keys and values can all be repeated"

My solution counts all key/value pairs rather than distinct key/value pairs. If that's not what you want, it's easy enough to change the logic.

Comment: I am still not getting back a count of zero for key 3.  I have edited my question with sample data and desired output.  FYI, I tried this using the WITH keyword as well, but had no luck

Comment: The WHERE clause short-circuited the outer join. This version gives you the output you want

Comment: Yep, I was just about to comment back here and say the same thing :).  All I did was change the WHERE to an AND to get what I was looking for though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
select distinct m.key, nvl( g.c, 0 )
from matt_test_key_values m
left join (
   select k.key, count(*) c
   from matt_test_key_values k
   left join matt_test_values v
     on k.value = v.value
   where v.value is null
   group by k.key
   ) g
on m.key = g.key
```

Comment: This works too, thanks for the alternative option. It will definitely be nice to have other options once i try to apply this simple example to the more complicated version of this i need to write

Answer (score 0):

Sample output would be helpful, but from you description, it sounds like this:

```
select key, count(*)
from matt_test_key_values
where value not in ( select value from matt_test_values )
group by key
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.    I have edited my question with sample data and desired output